# Как вывести из запроса к бд только значение без обозначения столбца из которого оно выводится?

Tags: javascript

Делаю запрос к бд и он мне присылает

```
password: '$2b$05$Lio4Wqpwn34XhZZFJjxtTenxhb6jXyP0//BVr6BkhNZGoKsjfmTrO'
```

Как мне вывести только саму строку с паролем без "password"?
Указал rows, но он выводит именно колонку и после неё значение, но как вывести просто значение?

Comment: пишу запрос через node.js и библиотеки pg

Answer (score 0):

```
db_pass.rows[0].password
```

ответ такой